# Count values using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have two tables, Table job and table employer.

**I am trying to count the number of employments of every job for every day**.
For example:

```
- job 1 has 5 new employee in day 2020-04-28 14:51:28.463
- job 2 has 3 employee in day 2020-04-28 18:11:23.111
- job 3 has 1 employee in day 2020-04-27 11:31:13.845
```

Well, so I should has in total the next information:

```
Day 28: 8 employee
Day 27: 1 employee
```

I am trying with this, but is not working because is giving to me the double, because for every new employee, a new row is created:

```
Select COUNT(convert(date, job.dateCreat ,103)) as jobsPerDay from jobTable job join jobEmpl jobEmp 
on job.Id = jobEmp.Id
Group by convert(date, job.dateCreat ,103) 
order by convert(date, job.dateCreat, 103) desc;
```

I am not using a subquery instead of the join because I need more columns that this.
If I use this, works but I can not get another column value from this second table:

```
Select COUNT(convert(date, job.dateCreat ,103)) as jobsPerDay from jobTable job join (Select distinct jobEmpl_id from jobEmp) as jobEmp
on job.Id = jobEmp.Id
Group by convert(date, job.dateCreat ,103) 
order by convert(date, job.dateCreat, 103) desc;
```

**Sample Data:**

[image: job Table]

[image: job Empl]

Comment: Can't you `SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(DATE, job.darteCreat, 103) AS "Day", COUNT(jobid) PARTITION BY (CONVERT(DATE, job.dateCreat, 103) AS Employees FROM jobEmpl`? Maybe `ORDER BY` something, too...

Comment: The column names in your queries don't line up with the column names in your sample data, so it's hard to guess what's wrong with the query. Also, pictures of data are not helpful. No one can copy and paste your data into a script to check a query. If you still need help with this, edit your question and add the data as plain text. See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
create table jobTable(id int, JobName varchar(200), dateCreat DateTime)

create table jobEmpl(jobEmpl_id int, id int, dateCreat DateTime)


insert into jobTable values(1, 'Police', '2020-04-28 14:51:28.463')
insert into jobTable values(2, 'Medic', '2020-04-28 14:51:28.463')
insert into jobTable values(3, 'FootBaller', '2020-04-28 14:51:28.463')


insert into jobEmpl values(5, 1, '2020-04-28 14:51:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(6, 1, '2020-04-28 14:52:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(7, 1, '2020-04-28 14:53:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(8, 1, '2020-04-28 14:54:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(9, 1, '2020-04-28 14:55:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(16, 1, '2020-04-29 14:55:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(17, 1, '2020-05-29 14:55:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(10, 2, '2020-04-28 16:51:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(11, 2, '2020-04-28 16:53:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(12, 2, '2020-04-28 16:55:28.463')
insert into jobEmpl values(15, 3, '2020-04-27 18:12:18.263')


select j.id as JobId, count(je.jobEmpl_id) as NoOfEmployees, convert(date, je.dateCreat ,103) dateOfJoining
from jobEmpl je 
inner join jobTable j on j.id = je.id
group by j.id, convert(date, je.dateCreat ,103) 
order by j.id


select day(je.dateCreat) dayOfJoining,month(je.dateCreat) monthOfJoining,year(je.dateCreat) yearsOfJoining, count(je.jobEmpl_id) as NoOfEmployees
from jobEmpl je 
inner join jobTable j on j.id = je.id
group by day(je.dateCreat),month(je.dateCreat),year(je.dateCreat)
```